# Fuzzy Multi Match not working as expected Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to write query for search as you type with fuzziness added.(elastic search 7.12)

```
{
"query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "query": "airl recl",
        "fields": [
            "tags",
            "display_text",
            "display_subtext"
        ],
        "type" : "most_fields",
        "operator": "and",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO:4,6",
        "prefix_length" :2 
    }
}
```

}

I have inserted docs with "airtel recharge" values. I am also using edge n gram(1:50) for above given 3 fields along with space analyzer.

1. If i search with airl -> it works fine, getting result with airtel keyword.
2. If i search with recl -> it works fine, getting
   result with recharge keyword.
3. But when i search with "airl recl" in query, not getting any result.

space analyzer :

```
"words_with_spaces_analyzer" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "words_with_space"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer" : {
        "words_with_space" : {
          "pattern" : "([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[\\s]*)",
          "type" : "pattern",
          "group" : "0"
        }
      }
    },
```

Mapping

```
   "display_text": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "words_with_spaces_analyzer"
            }
```

Can someone please help me in understanding why above given query behaves this way for multi token input whereas both the token giving output if run them separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use a [whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html), as a `search_analyzer`. This will break the search term `"airl recl"`  into `airl` and `recl`. And, then will perform the search on these individual tokens.**

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
 {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 50,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "whitespace"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "airtel recharge"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "airl recl",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ],
      "type": "most_fields",
      "operator": "and",
      "fuzziness": "AUTO:4,6",
      "prefix_length": 2
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67702617",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.22729424,
        "_source": {
          "name": "airtel recharge"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. I am trying your analyzer, but can you please check my current space analyzer whether it has any issue ?

Comment: @BhagwatiMalav `words_with_spaces_analyzer` analyzer will also work, you just need to use it as `search_analyzer` as shown in the index mapping above

Comment: i have adding mapping also for reference, can you please check once ? @ESCoder

Comment: @BhagwatiMalav are you using the same index mapping, as given in the question above ?

Comment: yes i think my analyzer end index/start of tokens getting overlapped that is creating the issue, i am checking with your analyzer now.